How to set an array value in another function using reactjs
I have two method in App.Js like below
function abc ()   {
    const a = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"]
}

function def() {
    // I want to use abc() array value of**a** here in def()
}

How to achieve this?

You can just extract the a array from the abc function ?

If you do not want to modify the content of array a then just return it from abc() and inside def() add a = abc().

import React , { useState }from "react"; import Papa from 'papaparse'; export default function App() { const [data, setData] = useState([]); const handleFile =(e) =>{ Papa.parse(e.target.files[0],{ header:true, skipEmptyLines:true, complete:function(result){ const filterResultArray =[]; filterResultArray.push(result.data); setData(filterResultArray); //FilterResultArray Having the value } }) } const calculateMapping = ()=> { console.log(data); //here data is not showing }

Simply define abc function like this:
function abc () {
   const cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab"];
   return cars;
}

And your def function will be like this:
function def () {
   const carsFromAbc = abc();
   console.log(carsFromAbc)
}

def(); // ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab"]


But If have a two methods like below
function handleFile (e) {
Papa.parse(e.target.files[0],{
header:true,
skipEmptyLines:true,
complete:function(result){
const filterResultArray =[];
filterResultArray.push(result.data);
})
})
}
function calculateMapping () {
//here I want to read  filterResultArray  value ..How to access
}

In this case, you can use states so you can access the array within all of your functions. Read more about states: https://react.dev/learn/managing-state

import React , { useState }from "react";
import Papa from 'papaparse';
export default function App() {
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const handleFile =(e) =>{

Papa.parse(e.target.files[0],{
header:true,
skipEmptyLines:true,
complete:function(result){
const filterResultArray =[];
filterResultArray.push(result.data);
setData(filterResultArray); //FilterResultArray Having the value
}
})
}
const calculateMapping = ()=> {
console.log(data);
//here data is not showing
}

You should define the calculateMapping function inside of the App function.

It has been defined in my actual code..Butin console I am not getting the value
import React , { useState }from "react";
import Papa from 'papaparse';
export default function App()
{
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const handleFile =(e) =>
{
Papa.parse(e.target.files[0],
{
header:true,
skipEmptyLines:true,
complete:function(result)
{
const filterResultArray =[];
filterResultArray.push(result.data);
setData(filterResultArray); //FilterResultArray Having the value
} })
}
const calculateMapping = ()=> {
console.log(data); //here data is not showing
}
}

Here's a simpler version of your code. Are you following this pattern?
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Papa from "papaparse";
export default function App() {
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const handleFile = (e) => {
setData("Test");
};
const calculateMapping = () => {
console.log(data);
};
handleFile();
calculateMapping();
}

Or another practice you can use arrow function like here:
const abc = () => ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"]

Then function def and run it.
function def() {
    const abcValue = abc()
    console.log(abcValue)
}

// run
def()

